# C++ ProjectEuler #11

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve the 11th problem on ProjectEuler.net. The goal for this problem is to find the largest product in a 20x20 grid of 4 adjacent numbers in any direction (up, down, right, left, diagonal).

I'm using the BigInteger library because I don't know how large will the numbers be and I don't want an overflow - but I think this might be the problem. Every time I restart the program I get a different answer. :/ I also tried to use an unsigned long long int just to see what will happen - the answer remained the same.

This is the code (Nothing complicated; I just test every element in the grid to see if it has 3 adjacent numbers in any direction, compute the product and set it as the new largest if it is larger than the previous one. On the end I print the largest product.):

```
//NO.11
#include <iostream>
#include <BigIntegerLibrary.hh>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    int grid[20][20] =
    {
        { 8,  2, 22, 97, 38, 15,  0, 40,  0, 75,  4,  5,  7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91,  8},
        {49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48,  4, 56, 62,  0},
        {81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30,  3, 49, 13, 36, 65},
        {52, 70, 95, 23,  4, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 01, 32, 56, 71, 37,  2, 36, 91},
        {22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 13, 80},
        {24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 03, 45,  2, 44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 12, 50},
        {32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 64, 70},
        {67, 26, 20, 68,  2, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63,  8, 40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 21},
        {24, 55, 58,  5, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 63, 72},
        {21, 36, 23,  9, 75,  0, 76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14,  0, 61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 95},
        {78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94,  3, 80,  4, 62, 16, 14,  9, 53, 56, 92},
        {16, 39,  5, 42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24,  0, 17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 57},
        {86, 56,  0, 48, 35, 71, 89, 07, 05, 44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 58},
        {19, 80, 81, 68, 05, 94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77,  4, 89, 55, 40},
        { 4, 52,  8, 83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 07, 97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 66},
        {88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72,  3, 46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 53, 69},
        { 4, 42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18,  8, 46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 36},
        {20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 04, 36, 16},
        {20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90,  1, 74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57,  5, 54},
        { 1, 70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52,  1, 89, 19, 67, 48}
    };

    BigInteger biggestProduct = 0;
    //unsigned long long int biggestProduct = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 20; col++)
        {
            BigInteger product;
            //unsigned long long int product;

            //std::cout << grid[row][col] << ":" << std::endl; system("pause>nul");

            //UP
            if ((row-1 >= 0) && (row-2 >= 0) && (row-3 >= 0))
            {
                product = grid[row][col] * grid[row-1][col] * grid[row-2][col] * grid[row-3][col];
                //std::cout << "  U: " << grid[row][col] << "*" << grid[row-1][col] << "*" << grid[row-2][col] << "*" << grid[row-3][col] << "=  \t" << product << std::endl; system("pause>nul");
                if (product > biggestProduct)
                    biggestProduct = product;
            }
            //DOWN
            if ((row+1 >= 0) && (row+2 >= 0) && (row+3 >= 0))
            {
                product = grid[row][col] * grid[row+1][col] * grid[row+2][col] * grid[row+3][col];
                //std::cout << "  D: " << grid[row][col] << "*" << grid[row+1][col] << "*" << grid[row+2][col] << "*" << grid[row+3][col] << "=  \t" << product << std::endl; system("pause>nul");
                if (product > biggestProduct)
                    biggestProduct = product;
            }
            //RIGHT
            if ((col+1 >= 0) && (col+2 >= 0) && (col+3 >= 0))
            {
                product = grid[row][col] * grid[row][col+1] * grid[row][col+2] * grid[row][col+3];
                //std::cout << "  R: " << grid[row][col] << "*" << grid[row][col+1] << "*" << grid[row][col+2] << "*" << grid[row][col+3] << "=  \t" << product << std::endl; system("pause>nul");
                if (product > biggestProduct)
                    biggestProduct = product;
            }
            //LEFT
            if ((col-1 >= 0) && (col-2 >= 0) && (col-3 >= 0))
            {
                product = grid[row][col] * grid[row][col-1] * grid[row][col-2] * grid[row][col-3];
                //std::cout << "  L: " << grid[row][col] << "*" << grid[row][col-1] << "*" << grid[row][col-2] << "*" << grid[row][col-3] << "=  \t" << product << std::endl; system("pause>nul");
                if (product > biggestProduct)
                    biggestProduct = product;
            }

            //UP-RIGHT
            if ((row-1 >= 0) && (row-2 >= 0) && (row-3 >= 0) && (col+1 >= 0) && (col+2 >= 0) && (col+3 >= 0))
            {
                product = grid[row][col] * grid[row-1][col+1] * grid[row-2][col+2] * grid[row-3][col+3];
                //std::cout << "  U-R: " << grid[row][col] << "*" << grid[row-1][col+1] << "*" << grid[row-2][col+2] << "*" << grid[row-3][col+3] << "=  \t" << product << std::endl; system("pause>nul");
                if (product > biggestProduct)
                    biggestProduct = product;
            }

            //DOWN-RIGHT
            if ((row+1 >= 0) && (row+2 >= 0) && (row+3 >= 0) && (col+1 >= 0) && (col+2 >= 0) && (col+3 >= 0))
            {
                product = grid[row][col] * grid[row+1][col+1] * grid[row+2][col+2] * grid[row+3][col+3];
                //std::cout << "  D-R: " << grid[row][col] << "*" << grid[row+1][col+1] << "*" << grid[row+2][col+2] << "*" << grid[row+3][col+3] << "=  \t" << product << std::endl; system("pause>nul");
                if (product > biggestProduct)
                    biggestProduct = product;
            }

            //DOWN-LEFT
            if ((row+1 >= 0) && (row+2 >= 0) && (row+3 >= 0) && (col-1 >= 0) && (col-2 >= 0) && (col-3 >= 0))
            {
                product = grid[row][col] * grid[row+1][col-1] * grid[row+2][col-2] * grid[row+3][col-3];
                //std::cout << "  D-L: " << grid[row][col] << "*" << grid[row+1][col-1] << "*" << grid[row+2][col-2] << "*" << grid[row+3][col-3] << "=  \t" << product << std::endl; system("pause>nul");
                if (product > biggestProduct)
                    biggestProduct = product;
            }

            //UP-LEFT
            if ((row-1 >= 0) && (row-2 >= 0) && (row-3 >= 0) && (col-1 >= 0) && (col-2 >= 0) && (col-3 >= 0))
            {
                product = grid[row][col] * grid[row-1][col-1] * grid[row-2][col-2] * grid[row-3][col-3];
                //std::cout << "  U-L: " << grid[row][col] << "*" << grid[row-1][col-1] << "*" << grid[row-2][col-2] << "*" << grid[row-3][col-3] << "=  \t" << product << std::endl; system("pause>nul");
                if (product > biggestProduct)
                    biggestProduct = product;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << biggestProduct;

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: You definitely don't need a BigInteger library. The largest possible product of 4 two-digit numbers is only `99^4` or 96059601.

Comment: Oh, silly me! I haven't thought of this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your problem are your range checks:

example:

```
// DOWN
if ((row+1 >= 0) && (row+2 >= 0) && (row+3 >= 0))
```

should be:

```
// DOWN
//if ((row+1 < 20 ) && (row+2 < 20 ) && (row+3 < 20 ))
//which still contains redundant comparisons (as pointed out by Blastfurnace), 
//and thus can be can be simplified to : 
if( row + 3 < 20 )
```

If you have random results on each run for a program, and you dont use concurrency, random number generators or something like that, most likely that randomness i caused by undefined behaviour like reading unallocated memory or reading using unintialised variables.

Comment: These compound tests are doing redundant work. For example, the DOWN test can be simplified to `if (row < 17)`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: You are obviously right. Although i prefer `row + 3 < 20`. That makes it easier to replace 20 with a constant variable by search+replace ;), and it will get optimized away anyways.

Comment: I think I got it now. I'll try to modify my program and see what I get. Thanks! I'll check back here a bit later.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I just changed >= 0 to < 20 in all of the tests in which I add a number to the row/col variables and I also got rid of those redudant tests. Are there any ways to optimize my code? Suggestions? Anyway, THANKS a lot for your help. ^^ Learning stuff every day.

Comment: @Tuntuni: Your code produces an answer quickly enough for this small dataset. I will hint that it's possible to reduce your tests and multiplications by half. If you recognize that the `LEFT` and `RIGHT` cases are symmetrical you can exploit that to only do a single `HORIZONTAL` case. The same idea simplifies the vertical and diagonal directions.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're reading off the bottom and right edges:

```
if ((row+1 >= 0) && (row+2 >= 0) && (row+3 >= 0))
if ((col+1 >= 0) && (col+2 >= 0) && (col+3 >= 0))
```

and the same test with the diagonals.

You should be checking that the index doesn't reach 20.

Answer (score 0):

visit this link for code
http://codingloverlavi.blogspot.in/2013/06/project-euler-solution-11.html

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

long find_max(int **);

int main()
{
                FILE *f;
                int **arr,i=0,j;
                arr=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*20);
                for(i=0;i<20;i++)
                                arr[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*20);

                f=fopen("D:/b.txt","r");
                if(f)
                                for(i=0;i<20;i++)
                                                for(j=0;j<20;j++)
                                                                fscanf(f,"%d",&arr[i][j]);             
                else
                                printf("file operation not successful\n");

                printf("Answer = %ld\n",find_max(arr));

                system("pause");
}


long find_max(int **arr)
{
                int i,j,k;
                long product,max=0;
                for(i=0;i<20;i++)
                                for(j=0;j<20;j++)
                                {
                                                /*checking for horizontal sequence*/
                                                product=1;
                                                for(k=0;k<4;k++)
                                                {
                                                                if(j+k<20)
                                                                {
                                                                                product*=arr[i][j+k];
                                                                }
                                                }
                                                if(product>max)
                                                                max=product;

                                                /*checking for vertical sequence*/
                                                product=1;
                                                for(k=0;k<4;k++)
                                                {
                                                                if(i+k<20)
                                                                {
                                                                                product*=arr[i+k][j];
                                                                }
                                                }
                                                if(product>max)
                                                                max=product;

                                                product=1;
                                                for(k=0;k<4;k++)
                                                {
                                                                if( (i+k<20) && (j+k<20) )
                                                                {
                                                                                product*=arr[i+k][j+k];
                                                                }
                                                }
                                                if(product>max)
                                                                max=product;

                                                product=1;
                                                for(k=0;k<4;k++)
                                                {
                                                                if( (i+k<20) && (j-k>0) )
                                                                {
                                                                                product*=arr[i+k][j-k];
                                                                }
                                                }
                                                if(product>max)
                                                                max=product;


                                }
                                return max;
}
```